# Java Graphical Halfing Mechanism Malfunction

Tags: java, graphics, exponential

```
g.setColor(c);
double changeFactor = (2<<count);
g.fillRect(x+1, y+1+(int)(boxHeight*(double)(1/changeFactor)), boxWidth-2, boxHeight-2-(int)(boxHeight*(double)(1/changeFactor)));
count++;
if(count == iterations)
{
    count = 0;
}
```

Above is the code for a graphical halfing mechanism that I've been trying to make. In short, the idea for it is a simple graphics exercise that starts with a filled bar and subtracts from its current height by half the height every 250ms. In this way, it is an exponential decline in height. This is the current output:

[image: gif]

[*Link* for those of you who are having trouble viewing the image](https://gyazo.com/e7ccea40d2fb860386ef58983c26f9ef)

This is the exact opposite of the output that I want. The white region in the bar is a flipped image of what I *want* the red region to do. Can you guys help me figure out why the code is not behaving correctly?

Sorry for the newbie question, by the way.

EDIT:
here's the answer:

```
g.fillRect(x+1, y+1+(int)(boxHeight*(double)((changeFactor-1)/changeFactor)), boxWidth-2, boxHeight-2-(int)(boxHeight*(double)((changeFactor-1)/changeFactor)));
```

Long story short, it's because I miscalculated the numerator for what I would want the height/y-coordinate to be.

Comment: I think your math is wrong, but are you clearing the box in between iterations?  I believe that if you fill the rectangle, but don't do anything to clear it, then next time you call `fillRect` it will fill in part of the rectangle with your color, but the part that was previously filled will still be that color--`fillRect` won't touch it, and it won't change.  Perhaps if you take care of that problem, it will be easier to spot what's wrong with the formula.  Or not--I'm not yet sure.

Comment: Thanks for responding ajb, and I know what you mean. I did set up a background-filling and repainting while loop using double-buffering, so the forgetting to erase issue would not be a problem. Either way, it would not change the fact that the red bar still climbs upwards rather than downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`fillRect` definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-), the second parameter is the location of the top of the box.  (In computer graphics, numbers often get bigger as you go downward along the Y axis, which is the opposite from how mathematicians draw graphs.)  Assuming you want the *top* of your bar to keep heading downward (as opposed to the bottom of the bar going upward), that means that the second parameter needs to keep getting larger.  However, in your code, the parameter keeps getting smaller, since `1/count` keeps getting smaller.

If `h` is the total height and `y` is the top of the box, then the successive values you want for this parameter are:

```
y
y + h/2
y + h/2 + h/4
y + h/2 + h/4 + h/8 ...
```

or, expressed another way:

```
y + h - h
y + h - h/2
y + h - h/4
y + h - h/8
```

Based on that, I think you can see how to make some small modifications to the code and get it to work.

Also, make sure you clear the box in between iterations.  `fillRect` won't touch anything outside the rectangle that you're drawing.  So if you want to make the filled part smaller, you have to do something to clear out the part that was previously colored that you don't want colored any more.

Comment: Thanks for the response, ajb. Please look at my comment above for my response to the last bit. In addition, I think I understood this much of it, but have been trying for hours to get a formula that properly works along with the type casting between int and double. Is there any chance you could provide me with that?

Comment: @DavidS. Since `changeFactor` is a `double`, `boxHeight/changeFactor` will be floating-point division, which is what you want.  The best way to convert to an int is `(int)Math.round(boxHeight/changeFactor)`.